# Excel: type() and WorksheetFunction.IsText() fail for long strings

Tags: excel, vba

Do other people find the following behavior? I'm running Excel 2007 under Windows 7.

In Excel VBA:

```
Public Function bTest_IsText(vArg As Variant) As Boolean
bTest_IsText = WorksheetFunction.IsText(vArg)
End Function

Public Function nTest_VarType(vArg As Variant) As Integer
nTest_VarType = VarType(vArg)
End Function
```

In Excel worksheet:

```
A1: =REPT("-", 255)
A2: =REPT("-", 256)
A3: =ISTEXT(A1)
B3: =bTest_IsText(A1)
C3: =TYPE(A1)
D3: =nTest_VarType(A1)
A4: =ISTEXT(A2)
B4: =bTest_IsText(A2)
C4: =TYPE(A2)
D4: =nTest_VarType(A2)
```

Cells A3:D4 result:

```
TRUE   TRUE     2   8
TRUE   FALSE   16   8
```

The return values 2 and 16 of `type()` have the [meaning](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899) "Text" and "Error value", respectively. The return value 8 (= `vbString`) of `VarType()` has the [meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) "String".

So it appears that `type()` in Excel and `WorksheetFunction.IsText()` in Excel VBA do not work if the argument passed to them has more than 255 characters. `IsText()` in Excel does not have this limitation. A workaround for the failure of `WorksheetFunction.IsText()` is to test for `VarType(...) = vbString` (which may be better anyway).

Are these legitimate bugs or am I doing something wrong?

Is there a place where verified bugs are compiled so I don't have to wonder if I'm going crazy when I see something like this?

Comment: Regarding the last part of the question, about whether there is a place where a list of such errors is maintained, I found one at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Quirks .

Answer (score 0):

`WorksheetFunction.IsText` seems fine if `vArg.Value` is used instead of the `Range` object directly. `=CELL("type", A2)` works too.

The `TYPE` function issue seems like undocumented limitation. It seems to be related to the ["Text values in formulas are limited to 255 characters."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386414/excel-use-formula-longer-that-255-characters) error, because the [documenentation Remarks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-function-45b4e688-4bc3-48b3-a105-ffa892995899) mentions:

> You cannot use TYPE to determine whether a cell contains a formula.
>   TYPE only determines the type of the resulting, or displayed, value.
>   If value is a cell reference to a cell that contains a formula, TYPE
>   returns the type of the formula's resulting value.

Comment: No, this is not about a "text value" in a formula. That error refers to long string constants, which are not involved in what I've described. And `type()` is not "return[ing] the type of the formula's resulting value". The formula's resulting value is of type `text`, but `type()` is returning `error value`.

Comment: @NewSites if you enter a formula `="....where the string value is more than 255 characters ...."`, you get the error pop up that I mentioned. From the documentation that I quoted seems that `=TYPE("-----.....------")` is evaluated where the long text results in error value. Also, `=ERROR.TYPE(A2)` results in 3 (`#VALUE!` error)

Comment: In the worksheet described in the question, there is no such error in cell A2, which has the argument of 256 characters, nor in cells A4 or D4, which are based on A2. It is only B4 and C4 that indicate an error. If what you are saying is correct, then there would be no way to pass strings longer than 255 to functions, which is certainly not true. The solution to the error you are citing is to build the string by concatenation. In the worksheet described, if you replace A2 with `=REPT("-", 255) & "-"`, you still get the same results in B4 and C4, so what you raise is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

## A Workaround!? (Nope!)

```
Public Function bTest_IsText(vArg As Variant) As Boolean
  Dim tArg As Variant
  tArg = vArg
  bTest_IsText = WorksheetFunction.IsText(tArg)
End Function
```

Came up with the answer after using this:

```
Public Function bTest_IsText(vArg As String) As Boolean
  bTest_IsText = WorksheetFunction.IsText(vArg)
End Function
```

which always resulted in TRUE, whatever you put in cell 'A2'.

So I would conclude that **your function wasn't doing what you thought it would do**.

Happens to me all the time.

Comment: Yes, of course your second function always returns `true` because you are forcing the argument to be text on its way in. It's interesting that you found that copying the argument to a new variable eliminates the error. But I think `VarType(...) = vbString` is a better workaround, and possibly the better way to do the test anyway. I just wondered if what I found was really a bug, and it seems that you got the same behavior, although you didn't say so explicitly. I still wonder if anyone has compiled a database of such bugs. Would be a helpful resource.

Comment: I recently read here on SO in an answer about some WorksheetFunction issue that 'you cannot pass an argument ...'  the rest is blank. I just can't remember, and wanted to put a link to it in my answer, but I couldn't  find it. I'm 100% sure about SO and WorksheetFunction, so if you wanna try to find it... This was the main reason I even considered investigating your question. I'm using Excel 2003 on WindowsXP and I got the same behavior as you did and I'm way over my head in here. Let's just conclude that I stumbled upon a solution. Thanks for replying.